# T-SQL Notification - Use HTML to create Chart/Graph

Tags: html, xml, t-sql, graph, charts

Is it possible to use xml and html to create a chart or graph to include in an email notification from MSSQL Server?

Has anyone done this before? Any suggestions?

For example: A chart visually representing the amount of receiving hours required in the warehouse for the next couple weeks.

Comment: Export the data from T-SQL to a small C# application and easily draw charts/graphs using word/excel interop libraries from Microsoft for C#.

Comment: Interesting. Let's say I'm very new to C#. What references or tutorials would you recommend to start down this path. I am very interested in becoming proficient in C#.

Comment: My reply is long so posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be tedious but this method works:

- Export the data from T-SQL (probably as a JSON) or directly use the database from .Net application.
- Now create a word template with some graphs (Line/Bar/Pie Chart or whatever) and bookmark it with some name 'my_chart'
- Now include `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` & `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` references in your C# project. (Google it & [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) also)
- Now in your C# project access those Graphs in word file using bookmark name & populate it with Data from database. ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264733.aspx))

It may take some time but **if your requirement is worth it** you can do this.
Also you **don't** need to study C#(it's very similar to Java) for this, just see interop C# syntax as you keep going BUT if you want see [C# documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) for any reference.

**Refer [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) also.**